# Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '962' for column 'date_id' at row 1

Tags: mysql, datetime

i'm trying to load data from one schema to another and got this error message.

can any one please help me resolve this issue

```
UPDATE flickr.flickr_photos, photos_dw.fact_photos, photos_dw.dates
SET fact_photos.date_id=dates.id
WHERE fact_photos.photo_id=flickr_photos.photoid AND 
DATE (flickr_photos.time_taken)=dates.date;
```

Comment: What is the type of the `time_taken` column?  Can you show us sample table data?

Comment: time_taken is datetime. look like - "'2007-08-20 05:09:05'"

Comment: And what is the type of `dates.date` ?